# Possible to use the Command-Line to map a solution in VS2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Our entire dev group just got new PC's at work.  We have roughly 15 solutions, and 4 branches for each solution. Rather than re-map everything through the UI, I was wondering if there was a way to map a solution via a command-line tool.

Comment: @Steve I guess OP is referring to re-mapping the TFS source control workspace.

Comment: @Jed You're possibly looking for [tf.exe Workspace Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Filburt from what I could tell that just created a workspace, I didn't see a way to actually map folders, maybe I just missed it.